# Word & letter count in an associative array

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn some PHP, and I've been banging my head against this problem for hours.  at this point, I'm pretty sure I've made it far more complicated than it ought to be (the last attempt I just scratched was ~100 lines long (admittedly, lots of comments).

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Read in a string, put the words in an associative array by number of letters, inside of which
is an associative array of words, sorted alphabetically, and the number of times they appear.

The next problems in the series build on this one, so I'm basically dead in the water until I can figure this out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you are trying to do. Can you rephrase the question? Or, maybe, give a sample input/output.

Comment: Ben - Sample input "this is my sample which is simple" -- sample output 2=>array('is'=>2,'my'=>1) 4=>array('this'=>1) 5=>array('which'=>1) 6=>array('sample'=>1,'simple'=>1) --does that help?

Comment: You can't force alphabetical ordering in an associative array.

Comment: Chris, googling turns up quite a few pages purporting to do just that.  I'm just learning this stuff, but are you sure about that?

Comment: You are correct. I retract my statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sample = "this my is sample which is simple";
$simple = explode(' ', $sample);

$words = array();
foreach ($simple as $word) {
   $size = strlen($word);
   if (!isset($words[$size])) {
      $words[$size] = array();
   }
   if (!isset($words[$size][$word])) {
      $words[$size][$word] = 0;
   }
   $words[$size][$word]++;
}
foreach ($words as &$w) {
   ksort($w);
}
ksort($words);
```

This is a bit nasty, but it gets the job done.  Note that I reversed the first "my" and "is" to show the alphabetical reordering.

Comment: Thanks, that does the job.  I was trying to use sort, and didn't think to specify &$w in my foreach loop.  Changed those two things and now my code works - I could've saved myself a couple hours of staring blankly at php.net if I'd come here first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no punctuation to worry about try this:

```
$words_by_length = array();
$string = "this is my sample which is simple";
$words = explode(' ', $string); //split the string by space to find all the words
foreach($words as $word) {
    $word_length = strlen($word);

    if(!isset($words_by_length[$word_length])) $words_by_length[$word_length] = array();
    $words_by_length[$word_length][] = $word;
}

ksort($words_by_length);
foreach($words_by_length as $length => $words) {
    $words_by_freq = array();
    foreach($words as $word) {
        if(!isset($words_by_freq[$word])) $words_by_freq[$word] = 0;
        $words_by_freq[$word]++;
    }
    ksort($words_by_freq);
    $words_by_length[$length] = $words_by_freq;
}
```